# Changing fonts in vscode remote SSH

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I am currently settings up a vscode remote environment, almost everything is working fine but fonts on Editor, output, debugger, terminal are not the one I chose.

## Setup

### Local

- OS : Windows 10 64bits
- vscode version 1.43.1 (NOT portable)
- User : has administrator privileges

### Remote

- OS : Debian 10.3 64bits
- User : is not root, ofc
- Root access is possible

## Current status

When running a local workspace, custom font is used (Source Code Pro Light) in editor, terminal, debugger, output ...
When running a remote (SSH) workspace on the debian box, custom font is not used (I check that it is installed)

```
$ fc-list | grep -i source
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/sourcecodepro/SourceCodePro-Light.ttf: Source Code Pro,Source Code Pro Light:style=Light,Regular
```

Here is a screenshot of the font it uses:
[image: Screenshot showing the font used by vscode]

I did run a text editor through x11forwarding and it was able to use the font.

Where did I made a mistake?

Comment: The display font is controlled by these settings: `editor.fontFamily` and `terminal.integrated.fontFamily`. What do you have in your settings?

Do you have a third container for configuration called `Remote` in addition to `User` and `Workspace`?

Comment: Hum ... a late answer @FSCKur, sorry, these months were quite strange.
I finally got it working without changing anything to vscode configuration.

I don't really know what happened though ... maybe something poorly configured on the remote